# Run a piece of code once before certain tests

Tags: java, junit

I am currently developing cleanup/migration code for our database. I want to run this code **once** when one or more of our database tests is ran (we have some non-database tests as well, and it is not needed run the cleanup/migration code).

I have already looked at the `@BeforeClass` annotation, but it runs for every class. So when I run 10 database tests, the cleanup/migration code will run 10 times as well, which is not really good for performance.

I was not able to find a good solution yet, so does anyone know a good solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) - it provides exactly what you're looking for - database build & teardown, plus all sorts of cleanup.

http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Unfortunately we already use another database cleaning/build tool which is called Flyway. I solved my question in the meantime by running the code inside a Spring Bean, which is ran only once before any tests.